# Designing multi module Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, application-design

Might be my question is abstract or out of context, but i am asking here since i have little idea how this happens.

I am wondering how big application/ platform break down there application in to multiple module and how they able to manage modules dependencies.

For example in some E-commerce application they tend to break down it in various modules like pricing,promotions,shipping.import/export and many more.
when we develop those application we hardly think about the underlying modules and how they have been designed to provides functionalists.

Most of those module are not web-applications but are standalone module and not deployed in the web-app as jar files.

can any one help me to understand how they break up things or is there any standard way to do this.any help/resources to get insight will really be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> E-commerce application [...] tend to break down [the application] in various modules
>   like pricing,promotions,shipping.import/export and many more.
>   [...]
>   Can any one help me to understand how they break up things or is there
>   any standard way to do this.

There are various ways from the technology point of view to modularize applications. Large systems are split into modules that must communicate with each others, and there are various technologies to do so: EJB, web service, libraries, database, file system, message queues, etc. It's way to vague to be answered.

In practice applications ten to be modularized according to the social structure of the company. This is [Conway's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law). Since pricing, promotions, shipping are usually different teams within the organizations, chances are that each team will have an engineering group, and the system will be modularized according to the organizational teams.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the various maven archetypes available out there.

for example: http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home

Answer (score 1):

You can package many EJB jar archives within an EAR archive.